# Reference connection strings in separate config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-config, connection-string

I would like to move my connection strings from my web.config file to a file called ConnectionStrings.config, both files are in the root of my web application.

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

**ConnectionStrings.Config**

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But when I try and run this I get the following error

> The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the
>   name of the section. (C:\Your Application\ConnectionStrings.config
>   line 2)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Web.Config**

```
 <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

**ConnectionStrings.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="name" connectionString="server=(local);database=db;user Id=usr;password=pass;timeout=0"></add>
</connectionStrings>
```

This is how (without the providerName) I do it and it works fine.